# How to send 2 parameters i angularjs to mvc controller?

Tags: c#, angularjs, model-view-controller

I have a post method in my js file which need to send 2 parameters.

```
    var patientData = { 'clinicalRegistryPatient': $scope.patientFile,'emailDetails': $scope.patientFile.emailDetails };
        Service.post(Service.API.REGISTER_PATIENT, patientData).then(function success(data) {
            toastr.success('changes saved successfully', 'Success');
```

}

and my api controller (mvc) is like

```
            public IHttpActionResult Post(CPatient Patient,EmailDetails emailDetails=null)
    {

    }
```

and in factory

```
        return{
       api{
     'REGISTER_PATIENT': '/api/patients/add
          }
            }

            post: function (api, data, headers) {

            var deferred = $q.defer();
            console.log(api);

            $http.post(api, data,headers)
              .success(function (data) {
                  deferred.resolve(data);
              })
              .error(function (err) {
                  deferred.reject(err);
              });
            return deferred.promise;

        },
```

but when i am invoking the api, it returns a 500 internal server error and I do not know where the problem is?

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: what is the code to your service?

Comment: are you tried to send one parameter is work ok?

Comment: yes its working with 1 parametre

Comment: You need to post the code to your Service. What you have is like missing a piece of a jigsaw puzzle

Comment: updated some part from service

Comment: If it's showing a 500 error you have issues with your backend service not the client side call most likely.

Comment: Not an answer to your problem, but just a suggestion...it isn't preferred to use .success/.error on $http methods as they are deprecated, instead use .then/.catch. Also, why do you use $q.defer to set up a promise, $http already returns a promise for you.

Answer (score 0):

1. Your api url is wrong; there isnt any action 'Add' in your controller (*unless you have attribute routing with action name as 'add'* );  POST 'api/patients'  should work if "Patients" is your controller name.
2. Rename 'clinicalRegistryPatient' to the exact param name in the Post method; in this case, it is 'Patient'